# Acclimating hardwood weight concern

Tags: floor, hardwood

I am having 3/4" red oak hardwood floors installed (1200 sq ft) and need to acclimate the wood.  The floor is supported by 2x10 joists (16" center) with a 13 foot span.  Can this wood be stacked in one location to acclimate is is it too great of a load for the joists?

Comment: That amount of weight located in a small area for a time might cause the joists and floor to develop a slight sag.  Most flooring requires a floor to be flat, having a slope on a flat floor is okay.  If a sag develops, then it needs to be levelled before putting the flooring down.

Answer (score 2):

At  45 lbs/ft3 that amount of red oak is 3375 lbs (nearly 2 tons) and is a lot of weight. Equivalent to maybe 12 full-sized refrigerators.

From pine load tables, dead load rating is ~80 lbs per foot so minimally you need a pile with a footprint of ~42 sq ft (5x8 feet) to distribute the load.

Comment: If it takes an area 5x8, then how high can they stack 1200 square feet of lumber.

Comment: 1200 sq ft / 40 sq ft = 30 layers. so 30 layers * 3/4" = 22.5". So 2 feet tall stack.